# How to find if an element contains subelement with id='x' using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Let's say I've got the following HTML:

```
<div class"my-class">
    <div id="something">
        blah
    </div>
</div>
<div class"my-class">
    <div id="something-else">
        <a href="/" id="x">bluh</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I loop over all elements of class `.my-class` I want to find the one that contains a sub-element (or sub-sub-element like in my example above) with id `#x`. So in the example above I want to find the second element with class `.my-class`.

So something like this:

```
$(".my-class").each(function() {
    if ($(this).containsSubElementWithId("#x")){  // <= HOW CAN I DO THIS?
        // Do something with $(this)
    }
});
```

Does anybody know how I can test whether an element contains another element with a certain id? All tips are welcome!

Comment: `if ($(this).find('#x').length)` should do

Comment: There are lots of complicated solutions shown, but I have added a very simple one for you below that gives you all the matches in one operation (no `each` required).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an even simpler way:

```
var matches = $(".my-class:has(#x)");
// Do something with the matching elements
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/kj1wzytw/

As you are looking for an ID-based element, which can only have a single match, the "fastest" search would be an ID search, followed by `closest`:

e.g.

```
var matches = $('#x').closest('.my-class');
```

but if you have multiple matches possible, (class or ID prefix etc), go with the first way.

e.g. (ids starting starting with `x`):

```
var matches = $(".my-class:has([id^=x])");
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/kj1wzytw/2/

generally a class search is almost as fast as an ID search, on modern browsers, so you would be better off using a class for multiple matches.

e.g.

```
var matches = $(".my-class:has(.x)");
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/kj1wzytw/3/

Comment: you are great man. the way you explain every point. i think i need to learn from you +1 :)  perfect answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `has()` method:

```
$(".my-class").each(function() {
    if ($(this).has("#x").length){
        // Do something with $(this)
    }
});
```

`$(this).find('#x').length` will also work.

Comment: `$(this).has('#x')` will become `[]` when this has no element whith id 'x' and `if ([])` is true

Comment: Surely `var match = $(".my-class:has(#x)");`, then do something to the `match` is better than keeping an `each` in jQuery? Added alternative below.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `each()` function and check the length of the specific element:

```js
var func = function() {
  $('.my-class').each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    if (that.find('#x').length > 0) {
      console.log('found!');
      // that.something()...
    }
  });
}
  
func();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-class">
    <div id="something">
        blah
    </div>
</div>
<div class="my-class">
    <div id="something-else">
        <a href="/" id="x">bluh</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I ask what the reason is that you take the extra step of `var that = $(this);`?

Comment: Just for further manipulation of $(this) object. eg: if (that.length > 0) { that.css({'color':'red'}) }

Comment: @kapantzak: May I suggest something for you? If you always use `$` prefixes for jQuery objects, `$this` makes a very readable variable to hold `$(this)`. (this also makes text editing of one to the other trivial) :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with -

```
$(this).find("[id='x']");
```

For checking it -

```
$(this).find("[id='x']").length;
```

Comment: Couple of things - the attribute selector is a lot slower than the id selector, and this will always return an object and therefore always equate to true. You need to return the `length` property.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. will take care from the next time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myClassElement = $(".my-class #x").parents('.my-class');
// Do something with myClassElement
```

If you want to do something with .my-class element event if it doesn't contain #x element use this:

```
$(".my-class").each(function() {
    var containsXElement = $(this).find("#x").length > 0;
    if (containsXElement){
        // Do something with $(this)
    }
});
```

Comment: question is to check for id available or not in children element . how this work ?

Comment: this example searches for the #x element in every .my-class container and if exists the parent .my-class element is returned

Comment: Thanks for this, it does indeed what I want. The thing is that I sometimes want to do something to an element if it doesn't contain the `#x` element Sorry, I should've mentioned that.

Comment: how this will help in `.each` loop . as you get each element with class `.my-class ` in loop

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating you can directly select the element by using [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
var elem = $('.my-class #x').closest('.my-class');
```

Now since an id is a unique, you can also do this:

```
var elem = $('#x').closest('.my-class');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".my-class").each(function() {

  if ($(this).find("a[id=x]")){
    //do whatever you want.
  }
});
```

Comment: This only checks for links, not for other elements with that id.

Comment: In that case try .find('#x'); or .find("[id='x']");

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to target the div that has the element, i would suggest you to find the element first and then traverse to closest parent div with required class:

```
var objhasx = $('#x').closest('.my-class');
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your initial technique:

```
$(".my-class").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // method 1
    if ($this.find("#x").length > 0) {
        // use $this
    }
    // method 2
    if ($this.find("[id='x']").length > 0) {
        // use $this
    }
});
```

More @

- https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/
- https://api.jquery.com/find/
- https://api.jquery.com/length/
- http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: `size()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.8. Use `length` instead

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know. I'll also be updating my answer accordingly